# SQL Server. Understanding search condition syntax

Tags: sql-server

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

I will be grateful for any examples.

**1. Part under question:**

> <search_condition> ::=
> MATCH (<graph_search_pattern>) | <search_condition_without_match> | <search_condition> AND <search_condition>

Is it a case of recursive syntax definition? For example:

`<search_condition> AND <search_condition>` resolves to `<search_condition_without_match> AND <search_condition_without_match>`

What "AND" is doing here?

**2. Another part:**

> `<predicate> | ( <search_condition_without_match> )`

Why this syntax distinguishes `<predicate>` and `<search_condition_without_match>`?

Comment: "resolves to <search_condition_without_match> AND search_condition_without_match>" - No. It resolves to `<search_condition> AND <search_condition>`. Essentially multiple MATCH predicates can only be combined using `AND`.

Comment: 1. Yeah, it's recursive. It allows constructive multiple search conditions like: WHERE 1 = 1 AND (somecolumn IN (1,2,3) OR some IS NULL) . In this case 1 = 1 is predicate, somecolumn IN (1,2,3) is another predicate, but whole thing in the parenteses is a search_condition. 2. This is same recursivity. Predicate is the "lowest" possible piece, while search_condition_without_match is the larger piece

Comment: Basically in this case AND is the only connector allowed.

Comment: If I correctly understand <search_condition> AND <search_condition> syntax applies to graph?

Comment: "WHERE 1 = 1 AND (somecolumn IN (1,2,3) OR some IS NULL)". Thank you for example. So this is why `( <search_condition_without_match> )` used with parenteses?